# PLS-DA in mdatools package in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to use the mdatools package to run a pls-da using the plsda() function.  I have data with 9000 variables and around 30 observations.  Each of the 30 rows are patients; the first column contains the clinical status for each patient (disease or control) and the remaining 8999 columns contain numerical data on the patients.  I used the following code to run the plsda:

```
plsda(data[,2:9000], data[,1], ncomp = 8999, coeffs.ci = 'jk')
```

When the code finally compiles, it returns an error, saying"Error in selectCompNum.pls(model,ncomp): wrong number of selected components!"

I chose ncomp =8999 as the total number of numbers from 2 to 9000...and the strange thing is, this worked well with a low number of components.  For example, when I tried

```
plsda(data[,2:10], data[,1], ncomp = 9, coeffs.ci = 'jk')
```

No error message is returned.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding how to select the right number of components?  I would greatly appreciate any help.  Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I am developer of the `mdatools` package and just came across your question accidentally. Number of components in PLS/PLS-DA is a number of latent variables. Every latent variable is a linear combination of original variables. Normally, you need much less components than the original variables, depending on the type of data number of components can be from 1-2 to 10-20. I recommend you to look at PLS part of the [tutorial](http://svkucheryavski.github.io/mdatools/) and ask me directly (e.g. by email) if you still have any questions or issues with the package.